# Mirth javascript import

Tags: javascript, mirth

In postprocesor script I need call API. I am using this code:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://www.example.com/something", false ); 
xmlHttp.send( null );
```

---

I got this error:

***ReferenceError: "XMLHttpRequest" is not defined.***
    at 8bb4dae5-0615-4f0c-8e60-26c8614a6bcc_Postprocessor:65 (doScript)
    at 8bb4dae5-0615-4f0c-8e60-26c8614a6bcc_Postprocessor:71
    at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptUtil.executeScript(JavaScriptUtil.java:547)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptUtil.executePostprocessorScripts(JavaScriptUtil.java:275)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptPostprocessor$JavaScriptPostProcessorTask.doCall(JavaScriptPostprocessor.java:104)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.call(JavaScriptTask.java:113)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

---

**How can I import XMLHttpRequest and using it in postprocesor javascript?**

Comment: And what's "postprocesor" ?

Comment: https://snag.gy/By9Ck0.jpg here you can see postprocesor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest is something specific to web browsers. Mirth Connect uses a JavaScript engine called Mozilla Rhino, which is not a web browser oriented engine (because MC isn't a web browser obviously).

Rhino *does* however seamlessly integrate with the underlying JVM. Basically anything you can do in Java, you can also do within JavaScript. Use [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) instead for example:

```
var url = new java.net.URL('http://www.google.com');
var conn = url.openConnection();
var is = conn.getInputStream();
try {
    var result = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is, 'UTF-8');
} finally {
    is.close();
}
```

Comment: Nick how do you use the same(mozilla rhino) to export, import or deploy a channel group while using the mirth connect rest api? Is there any good documentation on consuming the mirth connect rest api in the transformers or filters? I have tried to do a lot of research on this but I havent gotten clear documentation, infact this answer is the closest thing I have seen to my quest... @Nick Rupley

Comment: How to pass POST parameters though before conn.getInputStream()? Thanks